# java.io.InterruptedIOException when invoking next() over a ResultScanner object

Tags: scala, hbase

I am trying to read and parse a ResultScanner scanner, but when calling `next()` I get an exception.

This is the relevant piece of my code:

```
    var scan: Scan = new Scan()
    val keyRegEx : RegexStringComparator = new RegexStringComparator("^.*"+"123123123123")
    val rowFilter : RowFilter = new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, keyRegEx)

    scan.setFilter(rowFilter)
    scan.setCaching(3000)

    // Apply the scan to the Table
    val scanner = table.getScanner(scan)

    val scanOutput: Seq[(String, String)] = iterateScannerAddingRowkey[T](scanner, Seq())

  def iterateScannerAddingRowkey[T](scanner: ResultScanner, acc: Seq[(String,String)])(implicit m: Manifest[T]) : Seq[(String,String)] = {
    // **Line below is triggering the exception**
    val result = scanner.next()
    if (result == null) acc
    else {
      val rowKey = result.rawCells().head.toString.split("/")(0)
      // Parsing the rawCells content into a JSONObject
      val response : JSONObject = getJson[T](result.rawCells())
      iterateScannerAddingRowkey[T](scanner, Seq((rowKey, response.toString)) ++ acc)
    }
  }
```

And this is the exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InterruptedIOException    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:97)
>     at
>   com.myproject.framework.hbase.HBaseUtils.iterateScannerAddingRowkey(HBaseUtils.scala:85)
>     at
>   com.myproject.framework.hbase.HBaseAPI.hbaseGetRowByRegEx(HBaseAPI.scala:323)
>     at com.myproject.core.ComparePrefixVsRegex$.main(App.scala:46)  at
>   com.myproject.core.ComparePrefixVsRegex.main(App.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
>   Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.loadCache(ClientScanner.java:401)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:364)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:94)

As I understand in the case `scanner` was empty `next()` would return `null`

Anyone knows what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After trying several things I was able to solve the problem.

The main reason was the size of the table I was querying is really big, so I reached a timeout when processing the scanner. To solve this issue I made two changes:

I increased the spark broadcast Timeout

```
val spark = SparkSession
              .builder
              .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "36000")
              .getOrCreate()
```

And I added in the scan the selection of columns I want to read, to reduce the size of the result:

```
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("CF"), Bytes.toBytes("C1"))
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("CF"), Bytes.toBytes("C2"))
```